# Multiple skips when reading a csv file

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a very large file of which I only need the first element of rows 1, 100001, 200001, which I extract like this:

```
x1 <- read.csv(filename, nrows = 1, header = F)[1, 1]
x2 <- read.csv(filename, skip = 100000, nrows = 1, header = F)[1, 1]
x3 <- read.csv(filename, skip = 200000, nrows = 1, header = F)[1, 1]
```

I don't know how reading works, but I assume this forces some unnessesary reading/skipping.

I wonder if I could continue skipping after reading `x2` in stead of starting at the beginning of the file again. That would save some time.

I do not want to have the whole file (or the whole first column) in memory (at some point) if I can avoid it.

Comment: Might be relevant [Read lines by number from a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156770/read-lines-by-number-from-a-large-file/7156792)

Comment: I was _just_ about to answer that, @benson23! :-) Working code for a CSV: `con <- file("~/tmp/mt.csv"); open(con); read.csv(con, header=TRUE, nrows=5); read.csv(con, header=FALSE, nrows=5); read.csv(con, header=FALSE, nrows=5);` where the first call to `read.csv` has the correct headers (which you may want to store), and subsequent calls to `read.csv` must not look for a header row.

Comment: @Řídící, confirm this works for you please!

Comment: As an alternative ... while `arrow::read_csv_arrow(..., as_data_frame=FALSE)` does not support slicing by row number, it does allow lazy filtering and pulling only rows/columns you need each time. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/data_wrangling.html.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with `scan`. It assumes you are reading numeric data, if not include

```
what = character()
```

in the calls to `scan`. Test file at end.
Note that I'm skipping 10 lines, not 1000.

```r
fl <- "~/Temp/so.csv"

sep = ","
skip <- 10L

vec <- NULL
skp <- 0L
x <- scan(fl, sep = sep, n = 1L, nlines = 1L)
while(length(x) > 0L) {
  vec <- c(vec, x)
  skp <- skp + skip
  x <- scan(fl, sep = sep, n = 1L, skip = skp, nlines = 1L)
}
vec
#> [1]  1 11 21 31
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

This is the contents of the test file (40 rows).

```
1,a,21
2,b,22
3,c,23
4,a,24
5,b,25
6,c,26
7,a,27
8,b,28
9,c,29
10,a,30
11,b,31
12,c,32
13,a,33
14,b,34
15,c,35
16,a,36
17,b,37
18,c,38
19,a,39
20,b,40
21,c,41
22,a,42
23,b,43
24,c,44
25,a,45
26,b,46
27,c,47
28,a,48
29,b,49
30,c,50
31,a,51
32,b,52
33,c,53
34,a,54
35,b,55
36,c,56
37,a,57
38,b,58
39,c,59
40,a,60
```